# Java : Omitting a Word in a String

Tags: java

I have a String , from which i need to omit a particular word from it .

As shown below the String may contain a Word "Baci" OR "BACI" in it

I have written a sample program shown below which works fine , but i want to know if there is better way to do it ??

```
public class Test {

      public static void main(String args[]) {

            String str = "Mar 14 Baci WIC";
            if(str!=null&&!str.isEmpty())
            {
                if(str.contains("Baci") || str.contains("BACI"))
                {
                    str = str.replaceAll("(?i) Baci", "");
                }
            }

            System.out.println(str);

      }

}
```

Comment: I would have gone with `[BACI|Baci]` but I doubt that makes much difference.

Comment: You don't need `if` statement and `isEmpty()` check. It will not replace anything if `str` doesn't contain the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way here will be to not additionally check the existance of "Baci", i.e. without the following `if` check

```
if(str.contains("Baci") || str.contains("BACI"))
```

Comment: why my 2nd if condition  if (str.contains("Baci") || str.contains("BACI")) is not needed ?

Comment: Because replaceAll method will check for this and replace all occurences You needn't to check once more

Answer (score 1):

You could improve it a little by using the \b regexp (which matches a "word boundary") :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i) Baci\\b", "");
```

That way, you code will not replace "my bacil is..." with "myl is..."

Answer (score 1):

Your second `if` condition is unnecessary, since `replaceAll()` will replace zero or more occurrences of the `String` without error.

Answer (score 0):

you can .toUpperCase your String and then only ask for contains("BACI"). Inside the if block, then just call replace twice with both Baci and BACI.

Thinking it again, I think it's better just calling replace twice without asking if your String contains it or not. If it doesn't find anything to replace, then it won't replace nothing.

Hope it would be useful!